# convert arrays to json

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have two arrays like the following

```
  var array1=[10,20,30,40,50];
  var array2=["A","B","C","D","F"];
```

I want to convert them to json Like this

```
  var data = [
       { x: "A", y: 10 },
       { x: "B", y: 20 },
       { x: "C", y: 30 },
       { x: "D", y: 40 },
       { x: "F", y: 50 }
      ];
```

I need this data to use it in D3 charts.

Comment: That isn't JSON. It's still JavaScript. It's just a different data structure.

Comment: Your data variable is referencing a list containing arrays, not a JSON object. fyi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the two arrays have the same lentgh, then:

```
var array1=[10,20,30,40,50];
var array2=["A","B","C","D","F"];

var data = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; ++i) {
    data.push({ x : array2[i], y: array1[i]});
}
```